# How to preserve a navigation controller's state? (pre iOS 6)

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, segue, restore, preserve

I have a button in my root view controller (R) that triggers a segue to a navigation controller (N). Inside the navigation controller I can switch between all the view controllers (N.0, N.1, N.2, ...) on its navigation stack and all of these view controllers have a button to immediately jump back to the root view controller (R).

I want to achieve that - whenever the button in the root view controller (R) is hit - the navigation controller (N) shows up again with its previous configuration.
Example: If the last visible view controller before dismissing the navigation controller was (N.1) I want the navigation controller to show (N.1) again.

Currently whenever I trigger the segue from the root view controller (R) to the navigation controller (N) it's always the navigation root view controller (N.0) that shows up. (Does iOS instantiate a new navigation controller every time the segue is triggered? Or is it still the same object?)

How do I preserve the navigation controller's state and restore it when the navigation controller is presented again?

*(I know that in iOS 6 there is a restorationIdentifier property which can be used for this purpose. However I want my app to support devices running iOS 5 a well and there must have been some way to achieve this behaviour prior to iOS 6.)*

[image: Storyboard Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

A segue **ALWAYS** creates a new instance of the destination view controller.  Presumably you "jump" to the root controller with **popToRootViewControllerAnimated:** which presumably destroys all the popped view controllers, so there is nothing to return to.  If you want to navigate a web of view controllers you won't be able to use UINaviationViewController or segues.

Comment: I jump back from (N.1) to (R) by calling the method
`[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`
when the button is pressed. So I do not pop the view controllers on the navigation stack before jumping back to the root view controller. Is there no way to preserve the navigation controller's state at the time I press the button and restore it later?

Comment: A navigation controller is a stack architecture; I don't think you can make it behave this way.  In any case, if you want to do this you can't use storyboard segues because they always instantiate a new copy of the destination view controller.

Comment: Just like Charlie said, dont use segue from your root controller to show navigation controller. What you can try is programatically instantiate the navigation controller in your Root Controller, and maintain a reference to it in your root controller as an instance variable. Next time your have to show the nav controller again, see if there's already an instance instantiated, then use that to present otherwise create a new one. I am not sure if it will work or not, but give it a try.